# Does work Batch normalization when Batchnormalization=false to true in Matconvnet

Tags: deep-learning, mnist, matconvnet, batch-normalization

I am using matconvnet library. In the MNIST example the default parameter batchnormalization=true. But VL_NNBNORM() function has nothing(just comment lines). Is it working though this? or Am i have to change vl_nnbnorm function?
I mean that if i change batchnormalization=false to true, is it enough?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's enough. If you see faster convergence, it means batch norm is working.
vl_nnbnorm.m has nothing because it calls a mex file. This is how Matlab calls a mex file --- you have a dummy .m file with the same name.